# Cannot retain values of fields in control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have 2 controls Control_1 and Control_2. Control_2 belongs to Control_1.
These controls have information related to a particular object. I needed to do it that way because Control_2 is going to be used on other pages and needs to be reusable. Control_1 has a button which is when clicked, saves data from Control_1 to DB. This is how the event for the button looks like:

```
ibtnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
```

However, what I need is to figure out how to save data coming from both controls. To accomplish that I moved button to a page that contains Control_1 and on a Page_Load event I call a method SaveForm() when Page.IsPostBack. When doing that, inside of SaveForm() method I lost the data related to Control_1. Is there any way to retain the form data for SaveForm()?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can enable viewstate for the controls inside your user control. This will help to retain the form data from both user controls.

To save the data from both controls, you can create save method as a public method in each control and then call both from your main page where both controls are present.

Comment: The thing is that I have to work inside of the two controls. I do not touch the main page. Main page is a placeholder for the Control_1 and submit button. Control_1 is containd Control_2 and both controls need to get the data for the SaveForm() method.  And the data is not saved.